# User should input undefined amount of integers and then they should be divided into groups

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm very new at Java and I have been trying to figure this out, the assignment is to let the user put in an undefined amount of integers into the program and then the program should be able to dived and then print out the # of integers into each category. The categories are Integers that are over 100, under 100, equals 100 and the total amount of integers. When the user enters a negative # the program should end and print out the before mentioned categories.

The problem I'm getting is #1 Not all of the users input is added correctly #2 the while loop doesn't stop at a negative # but stops whenever it feels like it, for example after 20 different #.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me.

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int hundred = 0;
    int total = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter values, put a negative # to quit:");
    while (scan.nextInt() > -1)
    {
                if (scan.nextInt() > 100)
                 {
                     high++;
                     total++;
                 }
                else if (scan.nextInt() < 100)
                 {
                     low++;
                     total++;
                 }
                else if (scan.nextInt() == 100)
                 {
                     hundred++;
                     total++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     break;
                 }
    }
     System.out.println("Amount of # over 100: " + high);
     System.out.println("Amount of # under 100: " + low);
     System.out.println("Amount of # that equals 100: " + hundred);
     System.out.println("Total amount of # : " + total);
```

Comment: Please tell the exact problem that you are facing

Comment: I noticed I hadn't explain the problems so I added it. The problem is like for example I tried this: "Please enter values, put a negative # to quit:
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
1001
100
1001
99"
And got this result:
Amount of # over 100: 0
Amount of # under 100: 0
Amount of # that equals 100: 4
Total amount of # : 4

first of all I never put a negative # into the program and also there are way more # than just 4..

Answer (score 2):

Actully you are getting input in every condition check, i think it was wrong in your code. 
Try this....

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int high = 0;
int low = 0;
int hundred = 0;
int total = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter values, put a negative # to quit:");
int number=0;
while ((number=scan.nextInt()) > -1)
{
            if (number> 100)
             {
                 high++;
                 total++;
             }
            else if (number < 100)
             {
                 low++;
                 total++;
             }
            else if (number == 100)
             {
                 hundred++;
                 total++;
             }
             else
             {
                 break;
             }
}
 System.out.println("Amount of # over 100: " + high);
 System.out.println("Amount of # under 100: " + low);
 System.out.println("Amount of # that equals 100: " + hundred);
 System.out.println("Total amount of # : " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`scan.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) - It scans the next token of the input as in int i.e, each call to nextInt gets an input integer from the console.

So, you need to have exactly one `nextInt()` for one iteration of the loop. You shouldn't be having one for each of the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `nextInt()` the `int` returned is removed from the buffer – subsequent invocations of `nextInt()` won't return it. Your code checks the result directly when you should be saving it to a variable and checking that. This makes the program seem erratic, since not every input is subject to all the checks you put in.

Also notice that the `break` is unnecessary – you have already covered all the possibilities.

```
int input;
while ((input = scan.nextInt()) > -1) {
    if (input > 100) {
        high++;
        total++;
    } else if (input < 100) {
        low++;
        total++;
    } else if (input == 100) {
        hundred++;
        total++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand why what I did wrong. So obvious, feel a bit dumb right now...

Comment: @ChristofferCarlsson There's no reason to feel bad – the important thing is that you learned something. We all start at the beginning.